# How to read data stored to firestore using array?

Tags: kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I am using the following model class to add data into `Firestore`. But I am not able to retrieve data from it which are stored using `Array`. Could you tell me how to read data from the `Firestore` for some of the fields under `items` and `address` in my example?

name, pin_code, place are some of the fields under the `address`.

quantity, amount, item_name are some of the fields in the `items`.

How to read these data?

Used this model class to add orders to `Firestore`

```
    data class Order(
    val user_id: String = "",
    val items: ArrayList<Cart> = ArrayList(),
    val address: Address = Address(),
    val title: String = "",
    val image: String = "",
    val sub_total_amount: String = "",
    val shipping_charge: String = "",
    val total_amount: String = "",
    val order_datetime: Long = 0L,
    var id: String = "",
    val order_Status:String="Pending" 
) : Parcelable
```

I wanted to read the price from it

[image]

Following code is used to fetch data from `Firestore` and which is in my `FirestoreClass.kt`

```
    fun getOrderStatusList(fragment: OrdersByStatusFragment){
    mFireStore.collection("orders")
        .whereEqualTo("order_status","Pending")
        .get()
        .addOnSuccessListener { document->
            val list:ArrayList<OrderStatus> = ArrayList()

            for (i in document.documents){

                val orderStatus= i.toObject(OrderStatus::class.java)!!
                orderStatus.id=i.id

                list.add(orderStatus)
            }

            fragment.successOrderStatusList(list)
        }
        .addOnFailureListener{
            fragment.hideProgressDialog()
        }
    
}
```

Following is my `OrdderStatus` model class.

```
    @Parcelize
data class OrderStatus(
    val user_id: String = "",
    val title: String = "",
    val order_status: String="",
    val price: String = "",
    val order_quantity: String = "",
    val image: String = "",
    val order_id: String = "",
    val order_datetime: Long = 0L,
    val sub_total_amount: String = "",
    val shipping_charge: String = "",
    val total_amount: String = "",
    val address: Address = Address(),
    var id: String = "",
) : Parcelable
```

Following is

`OrderStatusListAdapter.kt`
.

```
   override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val model = list[position]

    if (holder is MyViewHolder) {

        GlideLoader(context).loadProductPicture(
            model.image,
            holder.itemView.iv_order_status_item_image
        )

        holder.itemView.tv_order_status_item_name.text = model.title
        holder.itemView.tv_order_status_item_price.text = "$${model.price}"
        holder.itemView.tv_order_status_order_date.text = model.order_datetime.toString()
        holder.itemView.tv_order_status.text = model.order_status

        holder.itemView.ib_order_status_delete_product.visibility = View.GONE

        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(context, SoldProductDetailsActivity::class.java)
            intent.putExtra(Constants.EXTRA_SOLD_PRODUCT_DETAILS, model)
            context.startActivity(intent)
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I could read data from `address` using dot notation but I am not able to get data for `items`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.
I used the do notation to read data from `Firestore` that was saved using `Array`. Only that I have to use the array index while reading.
I know all the experts here know this. But I am mentioning here what I did, so that if any beginner like me come across a situation like this then it may be useful to them.

holder.itemView.tv_order_status_item_name.text = **model.items[0].price**